# Trying to change id for multiple rows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the id for multiple lines in order to activate and deactivate the link, but It only works with first line. Is there a way to make it work on entire page?

I want to change all paragraphs at the same time

```
function changediv() {
    if (document.getElementById("enabled")) {
        document.getElementById("enabled").id = "disabled";
    } else {          
        document.getElementById("disabled").id = "enabled";
    }
}

<button type="button" onclick="changediv()">Display</button> <br><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a>
```

Comment: **[ID](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/attributes/id) of an element must be unique**

Comment: I want to change all at the same time

Comment: Surely this is a textbook case for a `class` rather than an `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, [ID](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/attributes/id) attribute of an element must be unique in a document

> The id should be unique throughout the scope of the current document

Now, the solution is to use a class to group similar element, and access all the target elements using that class, you can use [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for that as given below. I have used `querySelectorAll()` since it returns a non-[live](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection) [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

```js
function changediv() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.disabled, .enabled');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList.toggle('enabled');
    els[i].classList.toggle('disabled');
  }
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.enabled {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changediv()">Display</button> <br><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. Seems it works like desired.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` always returns you the first element with that `id`.

So, you should use a different selector if you want to select multiple elements, preferably with a class.

try this `document.getElementsByClassName` instead

```
function changediv() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("enabled")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("enabled").className = "disabled";
    } else {          
        document.getElementsByClassName("disabled").className = "enabled";
    }
}

<button type="button" onclick="changediv()">Display</button> <br><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disabled">This is a paragraph.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the enables and disabled as classes, instead of ids and than use something like this:

```
var enabledunits = getElementsByClassName("enabled");
for(var i = 0; i < enabledunits.length; i++)
{
   enabledunits.item(i).class = "disabled";
}
```

but be careful, because if you put both for loops behind each other, the second for loop will remove the effect of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use the class attribute instead of the id attribute.
Class names can be used multiple times while ids are unique.